# Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch

Tags: docker, npm

Во время запуска `npm`, возникает ошибка:

`Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch`

Дело происходит в докере.

Как её побороть?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53930305

Comment: Окай. (=.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В ядре определенное количество обработчиков inotify. Поэтому их число нужно увеличить:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

[Детали](https://medium.com/@bestafiko/npm-npm-start-error-enospc-system-limit-for-number-of-file-watchers-reached-bdc0eab0a159)